# Wildcard directory exclusions with robocopy -- weird case

Tags: robocopy

I need to get robocopy to exclude any file whose path contains a directory with a particular name. For example, "bar":

```
c:\foo\bar\a.txt
c:\bar\c.txt
d:\baz\bar\flub\d.txt
```

should be excluded, but not

```
c:\foo\barf\b.txt
```

Here are the things I tried -- each of which was rejected by robocopy:

```
/XD \bar\
/XD *\bar\*
/XD *^\bar^\*
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 24):

Turns out the /XD matches on the directory name -- not the full path. So you don't actually have to worry about matching the backslashes.

So to exclude directories (anywhere in the path) called "bar", a simple **/XD bar** will work. If you *wanted* to exclude "barf", too, you could use /XD bar*.

Sometimes the answer is simpler than you think.

Answer (score 5):

Part of the failure is using a trailing \ in Robocopy when referring to a directory - which is a no-no - as Robocopy tries to interpret it as an escape character. *Almost everyone makes this mistake in one way or another with Robocopy.* With that in mind, this example will work:

```
/XD "\Bar"
```

If you wanted to match a more specific folder structure (so as not to match other subfolders, you can add more detail, like:

```
/XD "\Foo\Bar"
/XD "C:\Foo\Bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

If your trying different directory filters, make sure to clear out your destination folder between changes!

A gotcha for me was that I didn't realize the ignore directory switch is applied to the destination folders as well. I had ran robocopy with `/MIR` and changed the source directory, and my destination directory updated as expected. Then I noticed I had archive folders I didn't want, so I added `/XD archive`, but my destination folder still had archive folders in it!

After messing with wildcards and including/excluding the `\`s, I finally tried deleting the destination folder and re-running the script - this time it didn't have the archive folders! Here is the command I was running, with the directory names changed to protect the innocent:

```
robocopy \\SERVER\Some\Folder\Path .\Some\Relative\Path /Copy:DAT /Mir /R:0 /W:1 /XD archive*
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but according to the documentation at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy:

> /xf <FileName>[ ...]   Excludes files that match the specified names or
>    paths. Note that FileName can include wildcard characters (* and ?).
>   /xd <Directory>[ ...]  Excludes directories that match the specified names and paths.

So this specifically means that wildcard can be used in the /xf flag but not in the /xd flag.

Comment: Maybe there's a bug in the docs? `/xd` can handle wildcards (on my win11 22H2) if there's no [back]slash in the specified directory.